# simple paint in javascript or flash

Tags: javascript, flash, paint

i'm looking for a simple paint script in javascript or flash
it must be free and possibly open source and it must be possible to save the generated image on server

something like canvaspaint.org would be nice but this one is buggy and i just need the brush/pen feature, possibly without the window like interface

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there's [JIT](http://thejit.org/) or [RaphaëlJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). In terms of the server-side, you could get the SVG generated by the second library using container.innerHTML and send it as-is to your server.